# Fixed button and slideshow in template upload per page

Tags: theme-development

For all products there is a different page. Every product page will have the product template. On this template I'll have 3 download buttons and a slideshow. Now I want that when making a page for a product that there is a option to upload 3 PDF's (for the download buttons) and up to 5 pictures for the slideshow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAsNG.jpg

To give an example
Page 'Blue car' will have blue_car_tech.pdf, blue_car_engine.pdf and blue_car_doors.pdf. The page also will have 5 pictures of the blue car for the slideshow. Page 'Red car' will have the same but in red.

Now when making the product page I want to select the product template and then there should be 3 button where I can upload the PDF files, and a button to upload the pictures of the products.

I really have no idea how to do this (or something what looks like this), so I was hoping you guys could give me a push in the right derection. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

With this plugin you can easy add extra fields to the backend of a page. You can also set it to show only when a specific template is selected.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man :)